# web page requires a reload before displaying javascript content... in all browsers other than MSIE

Tags: javascript, html

in all browsers I've trid other than ms internet explorer,
I need to reload before my slider menu is visable..
could anyone shed some light!?

http://www.musical-transformations.com/gallery/index.html

Thanks,

Comment: It's actually working for me in Firefox and not in IE8 or Chrome.

Comment: Also, the gallery itself is working fine in all three browsers: 
http://www.musical-transformations.com/gallery/gallery_vertical.html.  Consider using IE developer tools (F12 in IE8), Chrome developer tools (Ctrl+Shift+I) and Firebug (a Firefox extension) to debug the errors you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holy crap a frameset of framesets. What is this I don't even...

I think the browsers are having a heart attack and imploding. Refreshing it several times in firefox results in random rearrangement of frames, likely because they are not loading in a good sequence.

Try giving each frame an exact size rather than using the wildcard * for frame widths/heights and seeing if you can center things using % values or CSS (or maybe an iframe centered on the page).

Or better yet stop trying to tear a hole in the fabric of the internet.